# Order by array values in Linq to Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to write an OrderBy clause in a Linq to EntityFramework query. My problem is that the entity table I am looking at stores an ID, that relates to a table in a different database and I cannot adjust the database.

**MainDatabase.EntityToOrder**

```
ID
Name
OtherID
```

**SecondDatabase.OtherEntity**

```
ID
Name
```

My C# EntityToOrder Model looks like this, and I need to be able to order by "OtherName"

**EntityToOrder.cs**

```
public class EntityToOrder
{
    [DataMember]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long OtherId { get; set; }

    public string OtherName { get; set; }
}
```

So, I would like to Order EntityToOrder by "OtherName" in the most efficient way possible. My existing query looks like this.

```
var entities = mainContext.EntityToOrder.OrderBy(e => e.Name).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();

var otherIds = entities.Select(e => e.OtherID).ToList();
Dictionary<long, string> otherNames = secondContext.OtherEntity
    .Where(oe => otherIds.Contains(oe.ID))
    .Select(oe => new { ID = oe.ID, Name = oe.Name })
    .ToDictionary(oe => oe.ID, oe => oe.Name);

entities.ForEach(e => OtherName = otherNames[e.OtherID]);
```

How can I write the most efficient query to order by "OtherName", preferably avoiding selecting the whole EntityToOrder table into memory.

**Update**

For clarity, here is some code that achieves the OrderBy, but needs to retrieve the entire EntityToOrder table into memory. I was hoping this could be achieved in a more efficient way. Also, the OtherEntity can belong to many EntityToOrder rows.

```
var entities = mainContext.EntityToOrder.ToList();
var otherIds = entities.Select(e => e.OtherID).ToList();
Dictionary<long, string> otherNames = secondContext.OtherEntity
    .Where(oe => otherIds.Contains(oe.ID))
    .Select(oe => new { ID = oe.ID, Name = oe.Name })
    .ToDictionary(oe => oe.ID, oe => oe.Name);

entities.ForEach(e => OtherName = otherNames[e.OtherID]);
return entities.OrderBy(e => e.OtherName).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Comment: You cannot adjust the database but can you adjust the model (without any effect on the database of course)

Comment: Yes I could adjust the model, what change would you make?

Comment: I add an answer but it's not appropriate. Why don't you select the OtherEntity ordered by name first and then load your EntityToOrder ? Is it a 1-1 relation?

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting. But EntityToOrder can only have one OtherEntity, although OtherEntity can belong to many EntityToOrder. So not quite 1-1.

Comment: So you want to replace the first `OrderBy`, thus affecting the paging, by something from another db and table, which also is not unique (many EntityToOrder can map to one OtherEntity), is all that correct?

Comment: Yes, the paging will be affected so I need to call OrderBy before the Skip().Take(). And EntityToOrder.OtherID maps to OtherEntity.ID . So one OtherEntity can be mapped to many EntityToOrder.

Comment: OtherEntity table should be smaller then, correct?

Comment: Yes, in normal circumstances I would expect OtherEntity to be smaller, probably only 20 to 300 rows. EntityToOrder could be thousands or tens of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite challenging task. I was thinking initially just to switch the roles and perform pagination (OrderBy/Skip/Take) on OtherEntity table, but unfortunately that doesn't work due to one to many relationship. So I ended up with doing some pre pagination in memory on OtherEntity. However, in order to do that I needed counts of the matching items in EnityToOrder, so this is retrieved with additional db query, which makes the solution involving 3 db queries and some memory processing. Here it is

```
var countByOtherId = db.EntityToOrder
    .GroupBy(e => e.OtherId)
    .Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(e => e.ID, e => e.Count);

var other = new Dictionary<long, string>();
int skipCount = startIndex, useCount = 0;
foreach (var e in db.OtherEntity.OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
    int count;
    if (!countByOtherId.TryGetValue(e.ID, out count)) continue;
    if (skipCount > 0 && other.Count == 0)
    {
        if (skipCount >= count) { skipCount -= count; continue; }
        count -= skipCount;
    }
    other.Add(e.ID, e.Name);
    if ((useCount += count) >= pageSize) break;
}


var entities = db.EntityToOrder
    .Where(e => other.Keys.Contains(e.OtherId))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(e => new EntityToOrder { ID = e.ID, Name = e.Name, 
        OtherId = e.OtherId, OtherName = other[e.OtherId] })
    .OrderBy(e => e.OtherName).ThenBy(e => e.Name)
    .Skip(skipCount).Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Now, I'm not quite sure if that's better to what are you doing currently, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is likely as efficient as possible with the limitations of having two databases. It's a shame that you can't access a dictionary item by key in a query without having to use AsEnumerable().

Comment: @Joe Yeah. But that might be fixed in EF7 - I've heard some things, but haven't chance to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the model, then you might try the following:

```
public class EntityToOrder
{
    [DataMember]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long OtherId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OtherId")]
    public OtherEntity OtherEntity{ get; set; }
}
```

Then, you should be able to perform this query:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var entities = mainContext
    .EntityToOrder
    .Include(x => x.OtherEntity)
    .OrderBy(e => e.OtherEntity.Name)
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

**Edit :** 
Sorry, I missed the point that you had 2 databases....

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative which I thought I would post in case it is useful to anyone. I used a .Join() to merge the dictionary of OtherEntity into my query. This still selects into an IEnumerable so I don't think it is more efficient.

```
var entities = mainContext.EntityToOrder;
var otherIds = entities.Select(e => e.OtherID).ToList();

Dictionary<long, string> otherNames = secondContext.OtherEntity
    .Where(oe => otherIds.Contains(oe.ID))
    .Select(oe => new { ID = oe.ID, Name = oe.Name })
    .ToDictionary(oe => oe.ID, oe => oe.Name);

Func<EntityToOrder, KeyValuePair<long, string>, EntityToOrder> joinFunc = ((a, b) => { 
    a.OtherName= b.Value;
    return a;
});

return entities.Join(otherNames, e => e.OtherID, oe => oe.Key, joinFunc)
    .OrderBy(e => e.OtherName)
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

**Note on Includes**

When applying Join you select into an IEnumerable and therefore lose the ability to access properties from a linked table. To counter this you would need to add a .Include() for any linked table you need to access before applying the .Join(). E.g.

```
var entities = mainContext.EntityToOrder
    .Include("LinkedEntity");

return entities.Join(otherNames, e => e.OtherID, oe => oe.Key, joinFunc)
    .OrderBy(e => e.OtherName)
    .ThenBy(e => e.LinkedEntity.Name) //reference to linked table
    .ToList();
```